# how a cpu bound process switches between kernel and user mode

Tags: linux, kernel, signals

Recently I'm quite confused abount how linux kernel handle signal.

I know kernel call user registered signal handler when a process returns from kernel(ready to run in user mode). The most common case is syscall or kernel schedule task. So I write a program which is cpu bound without much syscall. And I run the program on a machine which has quite low load.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define USECREQ 10
#define LOOPS 1000

void event_handler(int signum)
{
    static unsigned long cnt = 0;
    static struct timeval tsFirst;
    if (cnt == 0)
    {
        gettimeofday(&tsFirst, 0);
    }
    cnt++;
    if (cnt >= LOOPS)
    {
        struct timeval tsNow;
        struct timeval diff;
        setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, NULL, NULL);
        gettimeofday(&tsNow, 0);
        timersub(&tsNow, &tsFirst, &diff);
        unsigned long long udiff = (diff.tv_sec * 1000000) + diff.tv_usec;
        double delta = (double)(udiff / cnt) / 1000000;
        int hz = (unsigned)(1.0 / delta);
        printf("kernel timer interrupt frequency is approx. %d Hz", hz);
        if (hz >= (int)(1.0 / ((double)(USECREQ) / 1000000)))
        {
            printf(" or higher");
        }
        printf("\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct itimerval timer;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = &event_handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = USECREQ;
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = USECREQ;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
    while (1) ;
}
```

since the machine has quite low load(24 core, no other tasks), I think there is no much schedule events.

I think the only kernel to/from user mode switch is clock interrupt, which is approximately 4ms or 10ms, which means the kernel won't call event_handler more than 1s/4ms = 250 times within 1 second. But surprisingly, the output is about 100000 and it takes only about . Does this mean there is about 111111 kernel schedule events?

```
// output
[root@my-centos ~]# time ./a.out
kernel timer interrupt frequency is approx. 111111 Hz or higher

real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.001s
```

what exactly is the time kernel deliver signal(not generate) to process?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, This line is wrong, because you are typecasting to double after the division operation (which will be in int)

```
double delta = (double)(udiff / cnt) / 1000000;
```

It should be:

```
double delta = ((double)udiff / cnt) / 1000000;
```

I am pretty sure the value of variable 'delta' would be very near to USECREQ/1000000, which means approx. 0.000010 seconds. *BUT* this line is also wrong. By dividing 'delta' by cnt you are holding  *AVG. TIME* (in second) of all SIGALRM received by the proess, but you needed accumulated time.

To know how many interrupts were delivered in a second line should be:

```
double delta = (double)udiff / 1000000;
```

It will be around 100 HZ.